# Angular2: Filter an array if item included in other other array

Tags: arrays, angular, filter

I am trying to filter an object array, so that all entries which are inside another array of id`s are kept. I tried different approaches but nothing worked so far.

The list with id´s:

```
list = [1,3]
```

Then the array to be filtered:

```
events= [{id: 1, name: "John"}, {id: 2, name: "Sahra"} ]
```

I only want to keep the entry with id: 1

Comment: You you have tried some approaches, mind sharing what those are or code your are currently struggling with?

Comment: I tried it with filter and some as well as filter and include, but I did not assign it to a new variable, because i thought just using the filter will change the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this is what you are looking for. Just use `filter` & `include` methods

```js
const events = [{id: 1, name: "John"}, {id: 2, name: "Sahra"} ]
const list = [1,3]
const result = events.filter(({id}) => list.includes(id))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: thanks, that worked, I already nearly had it like that, but I thought I can use the filter on the array without assigning it to a new variable.